# Storing lines into a List

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a file I am bringing into a RTB.

Let's say it looks something like this:

```
// Some Title
// Some Author
// Created on
// Created by
//

Format:
 "Text Length" : 500 lines
 "Page Length" : 20 pages

Component: 123456
 "Name" : Little Red Riding Hood
 "Body Length" : 13515 lines
 ........etc // can have any number of lines under 'Component: 123456'

Component: abcd
 "Name" : Some other Text
 "Body Length" : 12 lines
 ........etc // can have any number of lines under 'Component: abcd'



... etc, etc  // This can occur thousands of times as this file has an unset length.
```

Now what I would like to do is store everything from **`Component: 123456`** until it reaches the next `Component` *(which happens to be `abcd`)* and store everything into the `List<string>` position 0.  The next one will be in position 1.. and so on until the entire file is read.

Does anyone know how to do this? -- I don't necessarily need to use `List<string>`

Comment: Your question is too broad. I have the feeling you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: You should write an application that will do what you want.  If you expect us to deliver you an application based on your requirements you are in the wrong place.  If you have a specific programming question please ask it.

Comment: @Serge: I can specify for you if you'd like. It is not homework I am not in school.

Comment: @Abe: My specific programming question is: How do I store values from a keyword, in this case `Component`, and all the lines in between until it reaches the next line that starts with `Component`.

Comment: You shouldn't downvote a question based off of assumptions. Ask for clarification first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do something like:

```
// I'm assuming you're using .NET 4
var lines = File.ReadLines(filename);

var components = new List<string>();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("Component: "))
    {
        components.Add(builder.ToString());
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }        
    builder.Append(line);
    builder.Append("\r\n");
}

// Get the trailing component
components.Add(builder.ToString());

// Get rid of the first non-component part
components.RemoveAt(0);
```

(It's more efficient to ignore the bits before the first component, but it makes the code more complicated.)

Comment: Would I need to add another null checker `if (builder != null)` so that the `builder.Append(line);` and `builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);` is inside of it?

Comment: @theNoobGuy: Whoops, yes. Fixing.

Comment: @theNoobGuy: Fixed it to just remove the first element afterwards, which simplifies things.

Comment: This works great.. but I have a question. If I wanted to use this code and split the line if it starts with `"Component :"` by `var lineSplit = line.Split(':');` So I get the Component's string in `lineSplit[1]`. Now I am trying to compare this value to a different list using `foreach (var item in otherList) { if (item.PartNumber.ToUpper().Equals(lineSplit[1])) { //help here? } }`. So I only want to add the lines of each **Component** if the string matches another string in a different list. Is there a way to change what you wrote to do this?

Comment: @theNoobGuy: Sorry, I don't really follow what you're asking. I suggest you ask a new question, carefully, with examples.

Comment: Okay. I will put a follow up link in here. Thanks! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476536/only-add-to-list-if-there-is-a-match